# Quero deixar uma string com valor Zero

Tags: c#

estou com um pequeno problema, tenho um textbox que tem um valor em reais "999,99" e escreve um numero por extenso, só que o textbox recebe muitas vezes um valor incompleto como '23' Etc, eu quero que quando a pessoa digitar um valor incompleto o programa complete para mim. Ex se eu digitar '10' o programa completa pra '10,00'

Alguém tem uma sugestão?

```
string n1 = "";
        string Centavos_unidade = null, centavos_dezena = null;
        string Unidade = "", Dezena = "";
        string valor = "", virgula = "", Centena = "";            

        n1 = TxtNumeroExtenso.Text;           

        n1 = n1.PadLeft(7, '0');
        string zero = "0000,00";



 if (n1[5] == '1')
        {
            switch (n1.Substring(5))
            {
                case "10": centavos_dezena = "Dez"; break;
                case "11": centavos_dezena = "Onze"; break;
                case "12": centavos_dezena = "Doze"; break;
                case "13": centavos_dezena = "Treze"; break;
                case "14": centavos_dezena = "Quatorze"; break;
                case "15": centavos_dezena = "Quinze"; break;
                case "16": centavos_dezena = "Dezesseis"; break;
                case "17": centavos_dezena = "Dezessete"; break;
                case "18": centavos_dezena = "Dezoito"; break;
                case "19": centavos_dezena = "Dezenove"; break;
            }
        }
        else if (n1[5] != '0')
        {
            switch (n1[5])
            {
                case '2': centavos_dezena = "Vinte "; break;
                case '3': centavos_dezena = "Trinta "; break;
                case '4': centavos_dezena = "Quarenta "; break;
                case '5': centavos_dezena = "Cinquenta "; break;
                case '6': centavos_dezena = "Sessenta "; break;
                case '7': centavos_dezena = "Setenta "; break;
                case '8': centavos_dezena = "Oitenta "; break;
                case '9': centavos_dezena = "Noventa "; break;
            }
        }

        if (n1[6] != '0')
        {
            switch (n1[6])
            {
                case '1': Centavos_unidade = "Um"; break;
                case '2': Centavos_unidade = "Dois"; break;
                case '3': Centavos_unidade = "Três"; break;
                case '4': Centavos_unidade = "Quatro"; break;
                case '5': Centavos_unidade = "Cinco"; break;
                case '6': Centavos_unidade = "Seis"; break;
                case '7': Centavos_unidade = "Sete"; break;
                case '8': Centavos_unidade = "Oito"; break;
                case '9': Centavos_unidade = "Nove"; break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: apresente o código, um [MCVE]. E de que plataforma está falando? Windows Forms, Web Forms, MVC, Console APP e etc

Comment: Postei um pedaço do código, eh um pouco grande então resumi.

Comment: Um tratamento um tanto peculiar e suscetível a muitos erros... mas como você quer identificar quando o usuário não digitou os centavos?

Comment: Código bem peculiar, como disse @Leandro. Uma forma simples (e tão peculiar igual seu código) seria fazer um IndexOf(',') do valor de entrada, se for -1 quer dizer que não existe, então, você poe ',00'.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas vou tentar usar o IndexOf

Answer (score 0):

Implemente o seguinte método:

```
private void StringToDouble(ref string text)
{
    if (!text.Contains(","))
        text += ",00";
    else
    {
        string strCasasDecimais = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(",") + 1).PadRight(2, '0');
        text = $"{text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(","))},{strCasasDecimais}";
    }
}
```

Qualquer valor numérico que passar para o método, ser-lhe-á devolvido sempre com **2 casas decimais**, no formato `###,00`.

Depois poderá utilizar isto da seguinte forma (integrando com o seu código):

```
n1 = TxtNumeroExtenso.Text;
StringToDouble(ref n1);
```

A variável `n1` já terá as casas decimais corretas e já poderá prosseguir com a execução.

Answer (score 0):

Visto que você está a receber a `string n1` de uma textbox, podia e deveria usar um [TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
if (double.TryParse(TxtNumeroExtenso.Text.Replace('.',','), NumberStyles.Currency, new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), out double result))
{
    string n1 = result.ToString("N"); 
    // resto do codigo
}
```

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

`result.ToString("N")` converte a `double result` para string com o formato de 2 casas decimais.

`TxtNumeroExtenso.Text.Replace('.',',')` fará com que também possa receber o valor com o ponto `.` como separedor decimal.